# How to implement Couchbase circuit breaker on state change event?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, couchbase, circuit-breaker

I am new to using Couchbase. I have an implementation of the couchbase circuit breaker in one of our Spring Webflux-based applications.

Ref: [The official document](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/ref/client-settings.html#circuit-breaker-options)

```java
    public ReactiveBucket getBucket(String bucketName) {
        CircuitBreakerConfig.Builder circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.builder()
                .enabled(true)
                .volumeThreshold(45)
                .errorThresholdPercentage(25)
                .sleepWindow(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .rollingWindow(Duration.ofMinutes(2));
        IoConfig.Builder ioConfig = IoConfig.
                kvCircuitBreakerConfig(circuitBreakerConfig);
        return ReactiveCluster
                .connect(cacheConnection.getUrl(), ClusterOptions.clusterOptions(userName, password)
                        .environment(ClusterEnvironment.builder()
                                .ioConfig(ioConfig)
                                .timeoutConfig(TimeoutConfig.connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(cacheConnection.getConnectionTimeout())))
                                .build()))
                .bucket(bucketName);
    }
```

I need support to implement the below things.

1. I need to implement an event that triggers on Couchbase circuit breaker state change.
2. I need a method that will return the current state of the Couchbase circuit breaker.

Comment: I don't think you can.  In the core-io jar, CircuitBreakers are owned by Endpoints which are ultimately owned inside Nodes in Core, and as this is all internal state it's not accessible externally.  OOI what is the use-case?

Comment: Cross reference: [discussion on Couchbase Forum](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-implement-couchbase-circuit-breaker-on-state-change-event/34867)